# Google Sheets SumIf Formula Parse Error From Quotation Marks?

Tags: google-sheets, text, google-sheets-formula, sumifs, quotation-marks

In column A I have a list of products and one of those products has quotation marks.
In column B I have a list of quantites.

I want to create a SumIf Formular that sums Column B if Column A has the Prodcut Name *Quotation Example Name*.

The product name looks like this in the cell: "Quotation Example Name" Holiday Shortbread Cookie Pack

I wrote:

`=SUMIF(B:B, "A:A=""Quotation Example Name"" Holiday Shortbread Cookie Pack")")"`

How can I correctly write the formula to sum that item?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"""Quotation Example Name""",B:B)
```

[image]